# Python RegExp. re.match()

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст:`"'                DATE: 16/11/2018 13:25'"`
Нужно написать регулярное выражение для Python скрипта которое найдет эту группу `16/11/2018 13:25`
Я написал
`[\s]*(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}[\s]+\d{2}:\d{2})`
[По ссылке](https://regex101.com/r/vqLKZi/3) видно что паттерн находится но когда я вставляю его в код Python в функцию `re.match()` результат `None`

Код:

```
import re
pattern1 = "[\s]*(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}[\s]+\d{2}:\d{2})"
act_01 = "'                DATE: 16/11/2018 13:25'"
act_match_obj = re.match(pattern1, act_01, re.DOTALL)
print act_match_obj
```

Хочеться понять где ошибка.

Comment: У вас совпадение не в начале строки, так что используйте `re.search`. `re.DOTALL` вам не нужен, удалите.

Answer (score 2):

Функция [match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.match) требует совпадения начала строки с шаблоном, поэтому нужно немного подправить `pattern1`, чтобы с [match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.match) работало:

```
import re
pattern1 = ".+(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2})"
act_01 = "'                DATE: 16/11/2018 13:25'"
act_match_obj = re.match(pattern1, act_01)
print act_match_obj.group(1)  # 16/11/2018 13:25
```

Или используйте [search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search):

```
pattern1 = "(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2})"
act_01 = "'                DATE: 16/11/2018 13:25'"
act_match_obj = re.search(pattern1, act_01)
print act_match_obj.group(1)  # 16/11/2018 13:25
```

Если нужно вытащить несколько совпадений, то [findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.findall):

```
act_01 = "'                DATE: 16/11/2018 13:25'\n'                DATE: 16/11/2018 16:00'"
act_match_obj = re.findall(pattern1, act_01)
print act_match_obj  # ['16/11/2018 13:25', '16/11/2018 16:00']
```